# Finding the inverse of the binomial cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-theorem

I am trying to find a mathematical solution to the inverse of the binomial cumulative distrbution function, essentially mathematically representing the Excel function `BINOM.INV`.

Given a number of trials $n$, the probability of success $p$, and the cumulative area of the binomial distribution $\alpha$, I need to find a value $x$ such that

$$
\alpha = \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^x\binom{n}{k}\ p^k\;\left(1-p\right)^{\ n-k}
$$

So that if

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= 0.7 \\
p &= 0.3 \\
n &= 100 \\
\end{align}
$$

$x$ would be equal to $32$, replicating the following Excel formula:

```
32 = BINOM.INV(100, 0.3, 0.7)
```

How could I achieve such a value mathematically, not using Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statistical term for what you are looking for is the so called [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function). For a random variable with distribution function $F$ it is defined as follows:

$$Q(p)\,=\,\inf\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : p \le F(x) \right\} $$

For continuous, strictly increasing distribution functions, this is equivalent to:

$$Q(p) = F^{-1}(p)$$

The modification with $\inf\{\cdot\}$ is required for cases as the one you describe, where you have a non-bijective distribution functions. This is the case for discrete distribution functions such as the binomial distribution.

Notice that you wrote that you need to find $x$ such that:

$$\alpha = \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^x\binom{n}{k}\ p^k\;\left(1-p\right)^{\ n-k}$$

In fact such $x$ does not necessarily exist. Instead you are looking for the smallest $x$ such that:

$$\alpha \leq \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^x\binom{n}{k}\ p^k\;\left(1-p\right)^{\ n-k}=:B(n,p,x)$$

A very easy (naive) way to find this value on your own (for discrete distributions as the binomial) is to calculate the above right hand side for increasing value of $x$ until you find the first $x$ satisfying your condition:

With your values for $\alpha, n ,p$ we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
B(100,0.3, 0) &\approx 3.2\cdot10^{-16} \\
B(100,0.3, 1) &\approx 1.4\cdot10^{-14} \\
&\vdots \\
B(100,0.3, 30) &\approx 0.549 \\
B(100,0.3, 31) &\approx 0.633 \\
B(100,0.3, 32) &\approx 0.711 \\
B(100,0.3, 33) &\approx 0.779 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

As you can see, the first $x$ for which $B(100,0.3,x)$ exceeds $\alpha=0.7$ is $x=32$ which is also the output of the Excel formula.

Comment: Thanks, that is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a closed form expression for this? Or perhaps an numeric algorithm that is provably more efficient than binary search?

Comment: It appears there is not a closed-form expression for it. Quote "Binomial distribution does not have a closed-form quantile function" from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/248351/164057