# Probability with getting 2s on multiple 2-sided dice vs random number

Tags: probability, dice, programming

I need to roll n 2-sided dice (also known as coin tosses), and count the number of 2s (or heads) in the result.

Since I need lots of those in a computer program I figured I could maybe optimize that by instead just taking a random number between 0 and n, but i'm not sure if that's the same probability distribution?

I know the distribution of the total result of `n d2` is a bell curve, but I don't know this about `2s in n d2`, and for my optimization to work it would have to be evenly distributed (which I instinctively feel it should be, since all dice have the same probability of landing on either side, but I might be wrong here, been a while since I theoretically learned this stuff back in school, and forgot a lot).

So my question is: is "take the number of `2`s in `n d2`" the same as "take a random integer between `0` and `n`", and if not, why, and is there any other way i could "streamline" that calculation (because computers notoriously suck at drawing lots of random numbers fast)?

Comment: Just like in coin toss, the number of $2$'s is a random variable with binomial distribution where (for a fair dice) $p = 1/6$. It is far from uniform. If $n$ is large you can approximate this distribution with Normal distribution.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: @them these 2-sided dice are coin tosses, just lots of coins. so i feel rather $p=1/2$, but you're saying "how many heads in n coins" can't be (as i feared) approximated by "random number between 0 and n"? is there a way (except literally taking lots of numbers between 1 and 2 and then counting the 2s, because that'd be slow) to approximate this binomial distribution?

Comment: If this is a coin, yes $p=0.5$. What do you mean by "approximate distribution"? Do you want to draw a sample from binomial distribution? If you write a code, there must already be an implementation to draw a random sample from different distributions. Why not just draw $n$ tosses, just generate $n$ random binary outcomes of $\{2, not ~2\}$? If $n$ is large, then normal distribution (with the appropriate mean and variance) will very well approximate the binomial distribution so you can draw a random sample from normal distribution which most definitely implemented in some standard library.

Comment: yeah i want to draw a sample. what i have as the source is a (pseudorandom) uniform distribution. currently my code does `heads=0; for(i=1..n) if(random[0..1]<0.5) heads++;` but i was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this. $n$ is sadly not very large (usually $<10$), so i don't think that I have lots of options to approximate here (because they kinda fall apart here). i mean this also means the loop isn't going to be too slow, but since the program is running on my server and left open available to other users i'd like to minimize any chances of them clogging up my resources

Comment: If you have uniform distribution, why not assign $2$ if the outcome of a sample drawn from uniform distribution is larger than $0.5$ otherwise assign $not~2$, this gives you a single coin toss. To get $n$ tosses repeat this $n$ times.

Comment: @them that's what i'm currently doing, but as i said, if there's a way to do this without the $O(n)$ loop, that would be better for me, because of the performance. it's not a bad solution, i was just wondering if there was a better one i'm missing.

Comment: You can try to do inverse transform sampling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling , then combine it with  "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426069/finding-the-inverse-of-the-binomial-cumulative-distribution-function". But I'm in doubt it will be faster.

Comment: yeah i'm afraid for $n$ this small this is probably the best way. i'm just gonna prevent them from entering insane values of $n$ to prevent my code from taking too long :P

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that $n$ is small, here is a way to do it that will almost certainly be quicker than taking $n$ samples from the uniform distribution on $\{0, 1\}$:

1. Generate a random integer $x$ from $0$ to $2^n - 1$ (inclusive)
2. Count the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $x$ (this is often called 'popcount', so look up that term for an efficient way to do it in whatever language/environment you are working in).

This will give you the same distribution as flipping a coin $n$ times and counting the number of heads.

Comment: great idea if i was using a low level language, but this is actually a pain to do in my environment, because i have no way of efficiently accessing the bits "thanks" to abstract number objects, so i'm probably gonna stay at my current approach of taking $n$ samples.